# What is the proper way to prevent text from splitting across columns and pages?

Tags: page-breaking, tex-core, context, context-mkiv

I have some description environments which I do not wish to have split across columns or pages. Is there some command which can be placed around an item to ensure that it will never be split across columns or pages, unless it happens to be too large to fit within the height of the column?

- I am using ConTeXt, but plain TeX answers, which are generally compatible with ConTeXt are acceptable too.

Comment: You can wrap it around a `\vbox` or `\framed[align=normal]{...}` or `\startframedtext...\stopframedtext` and it will **never** break across a page or column.

Comment: `\vbox` and all `\framed` variants interfere with the `\topskip` mechanism which will lead to wrong spacing at the top of the page.

Comment: What about using `\startlinecorrection...\stoplinecorrection` when it interferes?

Comment: @Marco: Please provide an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Minipages, I have found to be quite useful in this regard.

```
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
.
.
.
\end{minipage}
```

of course, \textwidth can be replaced with something else that you prefer.