# ConTeXt equivalent of LaTeX samepage

Tags: page-breaking, context

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the proper way to prevent text from splitting across columns and pages?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52771/what-is-the-proper-way-to-prevent-text-from-splitting-across-columns-and-pages)

I'd be surprised if this has not been asked a zillion times before, but really I couldn't find it (tried `[context] "no page break"`, `[context] "preventing page breaks`, `[context] same page`, etc - to no avail). So with some trepidation, here is my question:

Is there a ConTeXt equivalent of LaTeX's `samepage` environment? Or another way to prevent page breaks? I understand that `\page[no]` prevents breaks at specific positions, but what I am after is something like `\startsamepage` ... `\stopsamepage`, if it exists at all.

ThanksI

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, so it was a duplicate, as I feared (of [What is the proper way to prevent text from splitting across columns and pages?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52771/what-is-the-proper-way-to-prevent-text-from-splitting-across-columns-and-pages)) - sorry about that.

If anyone stumbles on this question, a possible solution is:

`\definestartstop[samepage][before={\vbox}]`

I'm sure there are better ways, but this seems to work for me.

Comment: doesn’t work with columns sadly :(